# Did R2 lose the ability to fly?

Tags: star-wars, r2-d2

In *Attack of the Clones,* it is first revealed that R2-D2, using his thrusters, can fly.  The skill is used in excess in *The Clone Wars,* where R2 flies in almost every episode he's in.  But, in the original trilogy, he never uses this skill, even in situations where it could have been useful, such as the Sarlacc pit.

Did something happen to R2 to cause him to lose this ability?  Or is it simply that he's older now and can't function as highly?

Comment: [Related](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/116801/58193).

Comment: In the original trilogy R2 is already around 20-30 years older, so perhaps some of his "parts" are no longer working properly!

Comment: "A limited warranty on astromech rockets??" What a mess... Hate when plot demands such a stupid explanations...

Comment: Better the warranty expiring than the _fuel_ expiring...